# Função para criar Coluna

Tags: python

Olá,

Estou tentando criar uma coluna utilizando uma função, mas está dando um erro, que deve ser bobo de corrigir, e mesmo assim não consegui, vamos lá:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("Planilha_Final.csv")

# Criando Coluna com o Nome da Regua, Prazo e se tem ou não Crédito
df = df[df['Segmento'].str.contains('|')]
def cria_acao(string_nome):
    try:
        return string_nome.split("|")[0]
    except:
        return ''

def cria_prazo(string_nome):
    try:
        return string_nome.split("|")[1]
    except:
        return ''

def cria_credito(string_nome):
    try:
        return string_nome.split("|")[2]
    except:
        return ''

df['Régua'] = df['Segmento'].apply(cria_acao)
df['Prazo'] = df['Segmento'].apply(cria_prazo)
df['Crédito'] = df['Segmento'].apply(cria_credito)
```

Essa função acima deu certo, criou as colunas de prazo e tudo mais, o problema é na próxima, tentei criar uma função para que quando o valor da Coluna Prazo seja igual a 5 dias, ela crie uma coluna desconto com a informação de 10%, tentei assim:

```
def cria_colunas(string_campanha):
    if df[string_campanha].str.contains(' 5 dias ') == True:
        return '10%'
    else:
        return ''
df['Desconto'] = df['Envios'].apply(cria_colunas)
```

E o erro que aparece é o seguinte:

```
KeyError: ' 5 dias '
```

O espaço entre as ' ' em 5 dias é de propósito, a coluna está assim, coisa que vou tentar resolver numa próxima, mas eu queria saber o que estou errando na função.

Se alguém poder ajudar, fico muito grato!

Abraços,

Comment: Tenta normalizar as strings pra fazer a comparação. Se só tiver "5 dias" na coluna tenta usar o .strip() .. e até o "5 dias" in df["Envios"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua função `cria_colunas` recebe uma `string`. Fazer `df[string_campanha]` faz com que seja procurado uma coluna no `df` com o nome `string_campanha`. Como não existe essa coluna, ele gera o erro `KeyError: ' 5 dias '`.
O que você quer fazer é verificar se existe uma string na coluna 'Envios' e gerar uma coluna 'Desconto' a partir disso. Quando fazemos

```
df['Desconto'] = df['Envios'].apply(cria_colunas)
```

Estamos aplicando a função cria_colunas para cada linha da coluna 'Envios' e colocando a resposta na respectiva linha da coluna 'Desconto', criada agora.

A função correta seria:

```
def cria_colunas(linha_envios):
    if ' 5 dias ' in linha_envios:
        return '10%'
    else:
        return ''
```

Comment: Valeu @AlexCiuffa